# Вызов метода объекта после создания его экземпляра

Tags: javascript, объекты, методы

Имеется анимация снегопада на js

При генерации снежинок, значения свойств устанавливаются правильно

```
    var Flake = function () {
    var a = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 1) ? false : true;

    function randomPosX () {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxXRight - maxXLeft) + maxXLeft);
    }

    function randomStepX () {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 1);
    }

    function randomStepY () {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * 7 + 1);
    }

    function randomImg() {
        return "sf/" + flakes[Math.floor(Math.random() * flakes.length)];
    }

    this.currentPosX = randomPosX();
    this.currentPosY = 0;
    this.stepX = randomStepX();
    this.stepY = randomStepY();
    this.issRight = a;
    this.img = randomImg();
};

//генерация снежинок
for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
    window["Flake" + i] = new Flake();
    img[i].src = window["Flake" + i].img;
}
```

Но если попытаться вызвать метод этого объекта, то консоль пишет, что это не функция

```
console.log(Flake0.randomPosX());
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, дополните код, что бы можно было воспроизвести ошибку, а так же укажите ошибку, которая возникает у вас на данный момент.

Comment: в данный момент если вызвать `Flake0.currentPosX = Flake0.randomPosX()`, то консоль выдаст, что `Flake0.randomPosX()` - это не функция, тоже самое происходит если `Flake0.currentPosX = Flake.randomPosX()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У объектов, создаваемых вызовом `new Flake()`, нет метода `randomPosX`. Вы уже вызвали эту (private) функцию в конструкторе:

```
this.currentPosX = randomPosX();
```

и присвоили ее результат свойству `this.currentPosX`.

```
console.log(Flake0.currentPosX);
```

*Update*

```
var Flake = function () {

  this.randomPosX = function () {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxXRight - maxXLeft) + maxXLeft);
  }

  ...

  this.currentPosX = this.randomPosX();
  ...

};

console.log(Flake0.randomPosX());
```

Comment: Подскажите тогда как организовать выполнение метода у экземпляра объекта, если конструктор, выполнив код внутри себя, создал лишь объект с свойствами

Comment: Я не совсем понимаю, чего Вы хотите добиться. Тем не менее - см. ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, ваш ответ дал понять мне, что я делал неправильно

Answer (score 0):

Подозреваю что вашу проблему решит код ниже.
Вы устанавливаете в значения переменных класса `результат` выполнения функции, а не сами функции. Таким образом, вам необходимо либо использовать конструкцию вида `Flake1.currentPosX` либо заменить `this.currentPosX = randomPosX();` на `this.currentPosX = randomPosX;`

```
var Flake = function () {
    var a = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 2) == 1) ? false : true;

    function randomPosX () {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxXRight - maxXLeft) + maxXLeft);
    }

    function randomStepX () {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * 4 + 1);
    }

    function randomStepY () {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * 7 + 1);
    }

    function randomImg() {
        return "sf/" + flakes[Math.floor(Math.random() * flakes.length)];
    }

    this.currentPosX = randomPosX;
    this.currentPosY = 0;
    this.stepX = randomStepX;
    this.stepY = randomStepY;
    this.issRight = a;
    this.img = randomImg;
};

//генерация снежинок
for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
    window["Flake" + i] = new Flake();
    img[i].src = window["Flake" + i].img;
}
```

Comment: если указывать `this.currentPosX = randomPosX`, то значением свойства `currentPosX` будет код внутри функции `randomPosX`

Comment: Поэтому вызывать надо 
Flake1.currentPosX()

Comment: вы невнимательно прочитали вопрос - currentPosX - это не метод, а свойство объекта